# How to enable fetch POST in chrome extension contentScript?

Tags: google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm trying to call REST API in chrome extension. I managed to get fetch GET working , but couldn't make POST work. The body on server side is always empty. Here is my fetch request:

```
  let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/save/one"
  fetch(url, { method: "POST", headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }, mode: "no-cors", body: JSON.stringify(json) })
  .then(resp => console.log(resp))
```

When I examined the request on server, I did notice that the content-type on server is always "text/plain;charset=UTF-8". So, my headers doesn't seem to be passed over. However, "Accept" header did go through.

This is the headers on server:

```
accept:"application/json"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br"
accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7"
cache-control:"no-cache"
connection:"close"
content-length:"306"
content-type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

If I remove "Accept" from my fetch headers, I got this on server:

```
accept:"*/*"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br"
accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7"
cache-control:"no-cache"
connection:"close"
content-length:"306"
content-type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

Any explanation on this? So, how to make POST work?

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. Try making the request in your background script (in the future we will [have to](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nPu6Wy4LWR66EFLeYInl3NzzhHzc-qnk4w4PX-0XMw8/), anyway).

Comment: @xOxxOm Just tried it in background script and it's the same. Thx.

Comment: Works for me if I remove `mode: "no-cors"` but only on http web pages of course - because the content script cannot make http requests from a https page.

Comment: Strange. It doesn't work for me. If I use http instead of https, I get this error: `contentScript.js:133 Mixed Content: The page at 'https:....xyz.com/754182173.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http:....abc.com/api/save'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Make sure you're reloading both the extension and the web page when you edit the content script.

Answer (score 18):

You need to write the code for post method

### Listener

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {    
    if (request.contentScriptQuery == "getdata") {
        var url = request.url;
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => sendResponse(response))
            .catch()
        return true;
    }
    if (request.contentScriptQuery == "postData") {
        fetch(request.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: 'result=' + request.data
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => sendResponse(response))
            .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
        return true;
    }
});
```

### Caller

Content_script.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
        contentScriptQuery: "postData"
        , data: JSONdata
        , url: ApiUrl
    }, function (response) {
        debugger;
        if (response != undefined && response != "") {
            callback(response);
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            callback(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Rana why do you put `'result=' + request.data` as body? I see this `body: { result: '[object Object]' }` on the receiving side. Why can't I just send the request.data as json object?

Comment: Hi @newman,
This is the format to using just append the result string, not any specific purpose. you can change it only request.data.
About the object please check your request is correct to debug the code

Comment: @LeoColman This helped a lot, thank you. I'm trying to do multiple `fetch` GET requests -- the `request` from the Caller is an array of URLs. I've tried a `for loop` and then fetch each URL inside, but it displays an error in the Caller console where it lost the connection with the background script when I try to wrap the `for loop` in an `async` function or `Promise.all()`. Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @RajputVikashRana is the author of the answer, I just made one edit :)

Comment: Life saver comment ! :)